# Record Audio as an Android Service and stop it using a Timer. Recording length varies, and service doesn't seem to stop

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm recently (a couple of days ago) starting to work in JAVA so I'm pretty sure I'm making some basic mistake/s.

I have created an Activity that through a button launches a Service that records Audio. In it I added a timer that stops the recording and exits the service through stopself(). Hope that's the proper way to close it.

But, when I run the application it generates more than one audio file for the recording period (I set it 90 MIN), and they are chopped off in an unreasonable manner (some of them are 30 min, some 20 min, etc). and the service sometimes doesnt seem to stop.

My Service class:

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
 public class myservice extends Service {
     private MediaRecorder myRecorder;
       private String outputFile = null;
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
           // super.onCreate();  (not sure about this one)

            SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss");
            String format = s.format(new Date());

            outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                  getAbsolutePath() +  "/" + format + ".3gpp";

            myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

               try {
                  myRecorder.prepare();
                  myRecorder.start();
               } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                  // start:it is called before prepare()
                  // prepare: it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat() 
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   // prepare() fails
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

            Timer myTimer;

            myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
                @Override
                public void run() {

        try {
                          myRecorder.stop();
                          myRecorder.reset();
                          myRecorder.release();
                          myRecorder = null;

                          stopSelf();
                          //onDestroy();  I added this one to test it out. not sure.

                       } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            //  it is called before start()
                            e.printStackTrace();
                       } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            // no valid audio/video data has been received
                            e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                    }

            }, 60000 * 90); //90 minutes timer to stop the recording after 90 minutes

            }

        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            //onCreate();  
           // return 1;
            return START_STICKY; //not sure about this one
        }

        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // TO DO
        }
        public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TO DO Auto-generated method
            return null;
        }

        public void onStop() {

        }
        public void onPause() {

        }
//what about this one ?
       // @Override
       // public void onDestroy() {
//  myRecorder.stop();
//  myRecorder.reset();
//  myRecorder.release();
      //}

    }
```

My main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       private Button startBtn;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
      startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent svc=new Intent(getBaseContext(), myservice.class);
            startService(svc);


            finish(); //because I want to close the UI after service started
        }
      });

   }

}
```

Before using android services, I wrote the app using threads. It worked, but timer worked only for short periods, 10 min or less). Audio recording stopped at some moment (usually 30 min or much less) and this length was not fixed (though the timer was set to 90 min). Still don't know why but I assumed the Android OS shuts the thread off due to lack of resources.

Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I solved it, I'm posting my solution if someone faces similar issues. Apparently, services (when inactive [without interaction] for about 30 minutes) can also be closed by the Android OS. What I needed was a foreground service. Sample from the official documentation:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```